# How to compare two list and check if its equal or not?

Tags: python

I have two lists that I wanted to check if they are equal or not. How to know if a word already exists in a?

```
a = ['EAGLE']
b = ['EAGLE', 'APPLE']
```

Comment: Uhm Ehhh `set(a) == set(b)`

Comment: What does "check if they are equal" means?

Comment: Wait. equal as in? len? string matching? num of elems?

Comment: For example, I want to check if eagle already exists in a and if it exists it will go to apple next. I just wanted to know how to check if the previous words is equal to current words.

Comment: So you want to check if an element of one list exists in another list?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. :-) Please revise your question by clicking "Edit" and try to specify in more detail what you're looking for. This will help future readers coming here for help. E.g do you want to know if two lists are exactly the same (length, positions of values, etc), or if one list is a subset of another list, or simply if a value exists in a list of values?

Comment: @Noctis,  please accept the answer that helped you solve your problem by clicking on the tick sign beside it, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

OP:  *I want to check if eagle already exists in a and if it exists it will go to apple next.*

```
a = ['EAGLE']
b = ['EAGLE', 'APPLE']

for elem in a:
    if elem in b:
        print("Element exists")
```

OR

```
for i in range(0,len(b)):
    if b[i] in a:
        print('Found element: ', b[i])
```

OUTPUT:

> Found element:  EAGLE
>
> Process finished with exit code 0

Answer (score 0):

```
temp1 = ['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four']
temp2 = ['One', 'Two']


list(set(temp1) - set(temp2))
```

Output:

```
['Three','Four']
```